# extjs how to create production build?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am trying to create production build through the command "sencha app build production"(sencha 5.1.3). It gets created but some of the view is not being served.can some one suggest that how I should ensure all the required js file  has been loaded so that the minified app.js should serve fine. Or there are some other steps to create the production build.(I am using sencha 5.1.3)

Answer (score 1):

In order to have all files included you have have to reference them somewhere with one of the config `requires`, `uses`, `controllers`, `stores`, `views`, etc.

Sencha cmd determines also the order of inclusion with these configurations.

Comment: My testing build is working fine but when I go for production build some of the view doesn't render. It says "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." as warning and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)Ext.Boot.Ext.Boot.c.fetch @ localhost/:87" as errors.

Comment: The warning you have, I do have it in the development version, but not in the real version.

Comment: The error means that ExtJs is looking for a file with name `Ext.Boot.Ext.Boot.c.fetch`. This should probably be `Ext.Boot.c.fetch`. Look for all occurrences of this class in your code. There must be a place where it is misspelled.

Comment: this class "Ext.Boot.c.fetch" is not present anywhere in my extjs app. I searched the whole app but it didnot returned me any instances.@Lorenz

Comment: This is really strange. I'm sorry, but I don't know where to continue to look.